# Given a metric $d$, prove that $\sqrt[n]{d}$ is a metric

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

I'm having problem with the triangle inequality, since, for $n>2$, it's quite impossible to do the trick of taking $(d(x,y) + d(y,z))^n$.

Comment: Use the fact that $f(x)=\sqrt[n]{x}$ is convex function.

Comment: ... and non-negative convex functions are *subadditive.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm....

we know that $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z)$ and want to show

$\sqrt[n]{d(x,z)} \le \sqrt[n]{d(x,y)} + \sqrt[n]{d(y,z)}$ which, given everything is non-negative, will occur if and only if

$d(x,z) = (\sqrt[n]{d(x,z)}^n \le (\sqrt [n]{d(x,y)} + \sqrt[n]{d(y,z)})^n \le d(x,y) + d(y,z) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{n\choose k}\sqrt[n]{d(x,y)}^k\sqrt[n]{d(y,z)}^{n-k}$

Which is indeed the case as $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{n\choose k}\sqrt[n]{d(x,y)}^k\sqrt[n]{d(y,z)}^{n-k} \ge 0$ and $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z)$.